# AjaxLink toggle the visibility of another AjaxLink

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have two AjaxLink (both under the same container) and I would like to toggle their visibility such that if `linkA` is clicked, `linkA` is hidden and `linkB` is visible, and vice versa.

The following is my implementation of `linkA`:

```
linkA= new AjaxLink<Void>( "linkA" )
    {
        @Override
        public void onConfigure()
        {
            setVisible( showLinkA);
            linkB.setVisible( showLinkB);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick( AjaxRequestTarget target )
        {
            if ( condition_met )
            {
                setResponsePage( NextPage.class, getParameters() );
            }
            else
            {
                showLinkB= true;
                showLinkA= false;
                target.add( linkA, linkB);
            }
        }
    };
```

The hiding part works i.e. when `linkB` is clicked, `linkB` is hidden. However, when `linkA` is clicked, `linkA` is hidden and `linkB` is not coming back to visibility. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Ajax and you hide and show components you need to use `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` on them. Without this the "show" cannot find them and there must be an error in your JS logs.

Comment: Thank yous o much! Adding `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` works for me!